# dynamodb java many to one

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

i wanted to try out dynamodb

I was able to save a single Object.
Now i wanted to try to create a many to one association.

Many Tasks sould be attached to a single User.

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "User")
public class User {
    private String id;
    List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return this.tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Task> taskMap) {
        this.tasks = taskMap;
    }

    public void addTask(Task task){
        this.tasks.add(task);
    }
}

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Task")
public class Task {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Task(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setname(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and now i am trying to save the user with the coresponding tasks

```
Task task1 = new Task("test");
Task task2 = new Task("test2");
User user = new User();
user.addTask(task1);
user.addTask(task2);
userRepository.save(user);
```

I know it doesn't work like this but maybe someone can give me an example on how to do it.

in a relational database world the tables would look something like this

```
User
id|.....

Task
id|name

User_Tasks
user_id|task_id
```

But how to do it the right way with dynamodb

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are saving both User and Task in single DynamoDB table (i.e. User). Please annotate the task class with @DynamoDBDocument rather than @DynamoDBTable.

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public class Task {

}
```

- Add getters/setters accordingly and an empty constructor

Comment: that works fine ... needed to add setters for the ids and an empty constructor for the Task Class

Comment: how do i update a task now? do i have to save the whole user object again? or could i update a specific task individualy?

Comment: Using mapper I think it would be difficult to update the specific task. You may need to use low level update item api and should know the index of the task in the list that needs to be updated. Without the index of the task list, the update item api will replace the entire list.

Comment: so basically it would be a good idea to store it in different tabels if the Task is changed rapidly?

Comment: Yes, the best way would probably be to store the tasks in their own table with the user ID as hash key and task ID as range key. That gives you an easy way to query all tasks for a user while still enabling you to easily update each task without worrying about other tasks or the user attributes.

Comment: do u know of any example code that does that? trying and failing to implement it.